# Is it possible to divide time by distance? Is $\rm s/m$ possible?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, si-units

Is it possible to divide seconds by distance/area/volume? If so, how to imagine and understand such a thing, and also what do we get by dividing them both (if possible to do so).

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with $T/L^n$; in fact it's the kind of thing you run into regularly on tests. The kind of test that gives you problems such as:

*"Farmer John's tractor takes 3 hours to plow 2 acres, while Farmer Jim's takes 4 hours to plow 3 acres. How long does it take Jim and John to plow 10 acres?
"*

So here, the figure of merit is time per area. We could redo the problem with columnists (hours per column inch, $T/L$), or wine makers (months per vat, $T/L^3$).

The only reason the unit is unfavorable is that the times add harmonically, while rates add linearly (which is the point of these types of problems). Physically, there is absolutely nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to divide seconds by distance. Intuitively, this gives the time that an object needs to travel some distance. For example, if

$$v=\frac{d}{t}=4\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}}$$

and you want to get an expression with $\mathrm{s}/\mathrm{m}$, you can simply invert the term, which in this case gives $0.25 \mathrm{s}/\mathrm{m}$. So it is equally valid to say that the velocity of the object is moving at a velocity of 4 meters per second or to say that it needs 0.25 seconds to move 1 meter.

Similarly, one can write an expression like seconds per area or volume if a given area or volume expands at a known rate. A more every-day like example would be, for example, blowing up a balloon and you want to know the time that is needed to achieve a certain volume, as mentioned by Jonathan Jeffrey in the comments.

Comment: Easy: $t/V$ is useful if you're blowing up a balloon, and want to know the time to achieve a certain volume.

Comment: You have two different uses for the same symbol, $s$. Don't do that.  Units should not be italicized. Use the \mathrm{} function for units inside a MathJax environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide whatever you want, provided you don't divide by zero.

Inverse speed in s/m has pretty intuitive meaning - the number of seconds one needs to advance by 1 meter.

I even remember seeing somewhere something related to corrosion, written as 1.5 years per millimeter.

Answer (score 0):

As you have also asked in another question about unit Kelvin * second, I will give you a general answer: In majority of cases, what is under a multiplication of units is an integral, while what is under a division of units is a derivative.

For this reason, something with units $s/m$ probably has as origin the derivative of a measurement $f(x)$ in seconds where $x$ is a length.

Example, if we measure the time need to walk some distances, we obtain a function with values as f(1km)=1000s, f(2km)=2500s, ... . If we are interested in measure the effect of "be tired", we will see how previous function changes, that is, its derivative f'(x), that as units of seconds/meter.

Another example related to units $Ks$: measure temperature of an object across time, T(t), where T is temperature in kelvins and t is time in seconds. The average temperature during some interval $[t_a,t_b]$ is:

$$T_{sum} = \int_{t_a}^{t_b} { T(t) dt } $$
$$T_{avg} = \frac{1}{t_b-t_a}T_{sum} = \frac{1}{t_b-t_a}\int_{t_a}^{t_b} { T(t) dt }$$

Note in previous expression the integral has units of Ks.